# Get HTTP requests and responses made using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse to show in Fiddler

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, fiddler, httpwebresponse

Is there any way I can hook Fiddler up to capture requests and responses made using .NET HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but Fiddler is a web debugger (proxy). If your requests were send through the proxy, it captures it. Please describe, what you (really) want to do.

Answer (score 43):

The Fiddler FAQ gives the answer to this.

You essentially route your HTTP traffic through Fiddler (i.e. Use Fiddler as a proxy).

Here's some links that will help:
[Fiddler Web Debugging - Configuring Clients](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET2-0)

Which in turn links to here:
[Take the Burden Off Users with Automatic Configuration in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300743.aspx)

You can achieve this via some configuration settings in the web.config file (for an ASP.NET application) like so:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy
      proxyaddress="http://[your proxy address and port number]"
      bypassonlocal="false"
    />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) for complete details on the `<defaultProxy>` setting.

Alternatively, you can use a WebProxy object in your code using something like:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("[ultimate destination of your request]");
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("[your proxy address]", false);
request.Proxy = myproxy;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx) for complete details on the WebProxy class.

Also note the important "caveat" that is mentioned in the Fiddler FAQ:

> **Why don't I see traffic sent to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1?**
>   IE7 and the .NET Framework are
>   hardcoded not to send requests for
>   Localhost through any proxies, and as
>   a proxy, Fiddler will not receive such
>   traffic.
>
> The workaround is to use your
>   machine name as the hostname instead
>   of Localhost or 127.0.0.1. So, for
>   instance, rather than hitting
>   http://localhost:8081/mytestpage.aspx,
>   instead visit
>   http://machinename:8081/mytestpage.aspx.
>
> ...Or, if you're using Fiddler v2.1.8
>   or later, just use http://ipv4.fiddler
>   to hit localhost on the IPv4 adapter,
>   or use http://ipv6.fiddler to hit
>   localhost on the IPv6 adapter.  This
>   works especially well with the Visual
>   Studio test webserver (codename:
>   Cassini) because the test server only
>   listens on the IPv4 loopback adapter.
>
> Lastly, you could Customize your Rules
>   file like so:
>
> ```
>     static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession:Fiddler.Session)
>     {
>       if (oSession.HostnameIs("MYAPP"))
>       {
>         oSession.host = "127.0.0.1:8081";
>       }
>     }
> ```
>
> ...and then just hit http://myapp, which will act as an
>   alias for 127.0.0.1:8081.

Comment: in case it helps anyone, default value for http://[your proxy address and port number] is http://127.0.0.1:8888, you can check/change the port in Tools > Fiddler Options

Answer (score 11):

If you can't, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a similar tool that works at the network hardware level, so it can capture network traffic from any application.

Wireshark is a bit more complex than Fiddler, and more general, but it's a great tool to have in your toolbox, and worth investigating a bit of time into.

Comment: @Charming Anonymous Downvoter: Did you miss the bit where I said "If you can't"?  Forgive me for trying to be helpful.

Comment: @Richie: I neutralized the downvote as I also cannot understand why.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to modify the request URI, and it is `localhost` then there is a much simpler solution: change the hostname to `localhost.fiddler`.

This has no dependency on setting up proxies (whether setting `HttpWebRequest.Proxy` or the `<defaultProxy>` element in a `.config` file).

(From comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17316510/67392).)