# Trying to see Http requests in Fiddler using WPF Application

Tags: wpf, httpwebrequest, fiddler, webproxy

How to use Fiddler to debug traffic from any app (eg. C#/WPF app).

Basically my WPF Application makes webrequests to a REST server that exists on another server.

I try and set up my proxy to communicate with Fiddler as follows.

HttpWebRequest req ..
...
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("localhost.", 
proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
req.Proxy = proxy;

Have tried "localhost" (No "." at the end), have tried "127.0.0.1" and other permutations.

I have tried the sugestions at
[Get HTTP requests and responses made using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse to show in Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470634/get-http-requests-and-responses-made-using-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse-to-sho)
and other similar posts and still cannot see any traffic.

Any further ideas on why I am not seeing traffic would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In one of the answers to [the question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470634/get-http-requests-and-responses-made-using-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse-to-sho), did you see this note:

> Also note the important "caveat" that is mentioned in the Fiddler FAQ:
>
> Why don't I see traffic sent to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1?
>   IE7 and the .NET Framework are hardcoded not to send requests for
>   Localhost through any proxies, and as a proxy, Fiddler will not
>   receive such traffic.

There are some alternatives mentioned there that might help you catch that traffic.

Comment: Im also trying to send traffic, to addresses that are  not localhost and do not see any traffic? Incidentally I tried using Fiddler on another PC with my app and it worked(though for some reason it mucked up my other functionality like http streaming). SOme mysterious reaosn I cant figure out why it does not work on my PC

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your machine name instead of *localhost*.
If that doesn't help, Add the following section into your config file.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled = "true">
    <proxy bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Find more details [here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp)