# Get xml data from external website

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an app that gets a daily feed from an external rss feed (this data is in xml).
I have a search form that allows users to search my database, however, i would like to use the same searchstring that users enter on my site to search this rss feed, then extract only whats relevant, and display that on my website.

I have been looking at reading xml file using linq using this code:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\Employees.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
Console.WriteLine("List of all Employee Names along with their ID:");
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has Employee ID {1}",
        employee.Element("Name").Value,
        employee.Element("EmpId").Value);
}
```

the problem i have with this is, where in the code do i use a url instead of a file name:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\Employees.xml");
```

should be:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("http://www.test.com/file.xml");
```

I am thinking maybe i should store the content into an array or something, and check to make sure if the searchString is in it?

I am not sure how to proceed and whats best to use, maybe i shouldn't even use linq??

so using the responses below here is what i have done:

```
public void myXMLTest()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.test.com/file.xml");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(dataStream); 
            IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();


            MessageBox.Show("List of all Employee Names along with their ID:");

            foreach (var employee in employees)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(employee.Name.ToString()); 
                /* the above message box gives me this:
                {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id
                {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}name
                {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title
                etc
                */
                MessageBox.Show(employee.Element("name").Value);//this gives me error
            }
        }
```

Comment: In my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412494/timeout-error-when-loading-xml-from-url/10412665#10412665 I give a generic method for returning an XmlDocument from a URL. It would require minimal work to convert to returning an XDocument.

Comment: If this is a standard RSS format (RSS or Atom), you will need to handle the namespaces in your LINQ statements as well.

Comment: please see my new edits based on your comments

Comment: @Menew - What is the error you get? Can you post the XML you receive back from the URL, or a portion of it?

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to do a bit more work than just providing it a URL.

Instead, you're going to need to get the XML file using the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx) class.  Provided the request is successful, you can then turn around use that as your argument to XElement.Load.

Example (illustrative only, for the love of Pete add some error handling):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.test.com/file.xml");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
XElement doc = Xelement.Load(dataStream);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, see my edits based on your suggested answer.

Comment: @Menew Your edits don't suggest what question you're trying to ask.  It might be better to ask another question.