# Free webhosting not letting WebRequest get the page

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am creating a chat application and I am using a free webhosting to store the online users in a database. I have the following structure:

1) `index.php` where i get the online users in this format:

> ```
> <user>
>    <name></name>
>    <ip></ip>
> </user>
> ```

2) `add.php?user=` to add a new user to the database when he connects.

3) `remove.php?user=` to remove a user when he disconnects.

Now in the application I have a function `GetUsers()` like this:

```
string url = @"http://.../index.php";
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

System.Net.WebResponse res = (System.Net.WebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

If I am using the local IIS server for the url it works but when I try with the free webhosted url it gives me an `406 Not Acceptable` error. So I think I need to put some headers or something to fake a real browser.

**UPDATE:** 1) The free hosting service is using Apache as the webserver.
            2) You can suggest another approach to fetch the web page.

Comment: I suggest using a tool like fiddler to capture your browser's requests, and then trying to simulate them in code.

Comment: @argaz thanks for the comment I indeed found that the problem was the `User-Agent` header. So post an Answer or something so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to capture your browser's requests, and then trying to simulate them in code.

You can also route your programmatic requests through Fiddler using the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470730/2464167).
Shortly:

```
req.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888", false);
```

`localhost:8888` is the default address of Fiddler.