# Can't see raw http request for HttpWebResponse, using Fiddler

Tags: shopify, fiddler, httpwebresponse

- I'm getting an error when trying to make a json request to a remote Shopify API using HttpWebResponse
- It fails on this line - HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()
- The error is server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity
- The JSON is well-formed, and the data is correct
- When I check using Fiddler on my local machine, there is no http request being made
- How can I diagnose the issue, or what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: For Fiddler, take a look at this SO Article: [Get HTTP requests and responses made using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse to show in Fiddler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470634/get-http-requests-and-responses-made-using-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse-to-sho)

Comment: See this Shopify Forum discussion: [How can I see exact Errors via API testing](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/how-can-i-see-exact-errors-via-api-testing-198083)

Comment: Thanks jdigital. If you want points, put this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`