# Configuring Fiddler to capture sessions between two local IISExpress sites?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, fiddler, iis-express

Is there a way to configure Fiddler 4.6 to capture traffic from one instance of IISExpress running on my Dev machine to a second IISExpress instance running on the same Dev machine?

I am using VS 2017 with one web site that is accessing some Web API methods on a second site running on another instance of IISExpress.

All of the browser to server traffic is captured fine, but I need to go from site to site to test some API calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTTP requests and responses made using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse to show in Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470634/get-http-requests-and-responses-made-using-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse-to-sho)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not so clear, but if you wants to communicate one IIS with another, you need to add a proxy like in the example:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                        {
                            Proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888", false),
                            UseProxy = true
                        }
```

For more info take a look at the [Fiddler docs](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy)